# ng-click not working with mmenu

Tags: angularjs, mmenu

I trying to use mmenu menu http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/ with my angularJS base app.
ui-sref is working but **ng-click is not working** with mmenu link. 
Can anyone help me, what wrong I am doing it.

Main HTML Page

```
<body ng-app="student">
            </div>
            <div class="header"><a href="#menu"></a>menu</div>
            <div class="content">
                    <div ui-view></div>
            </div>
            <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li ><a ng-href=""  ng-click="holidayInfo()">Holiday</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="notices">Notices</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</body>
```

app.js

```
app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider','RestangularProvider',
        function ($urlRouterProvider,   $stateProvider, $locationProvider, RestangularProvider ) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
            $stateProvider
                .state("home", {
                    url: "/",
                    templateUrl: 'home.html',
                    controller:'homeCtrl as vm',
                    resolve: {
                        currentyear: function (Restangular, $stateParams) {
                            return Restangular.one('CurrentACYear').get();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .state("notices", {
                    url: "/notices",
                    templateUrl: 'notices.html',
                    controller:'schoolNoticesCtrl as vm',
                    resolve: {
                        notciesList: function (Restangular, $stateParams) {
                            return Restangular.one('notices').get();
                        }
                    }
                })
```

My `holidayInfo()` method is in     homeCtrl controller.
When I do `<nav id="menu" ng-controller="homeCtrl">` it throw error, not able to resolve currentyear .

Comment: do you really need ng-href? try to set href=javascript:;

Answer (score 0):

You had `#` in the href of `Holiday` which is executing `$urlRouter.otherwise` code which is fallback URL.

It should be kept as blank

```
ng-href=""
```

---

Other thing would be you havent't had `nav` bar wrap with scope of controller where you wrote `holidayInfo` method. There you can have new controller for your `navbar` component & have `holidayInfo` method over there.

**Markup**

```
<nav id="menu" ng-controller="navbarCtrl">
  <ul>
      <li><a ng-href="#"  ng-click="holidayInfo()">Holiday</a></li>
      <li><a ui-sref="notices">Notices</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Code**

```
app.controller('navbarCtrl', function(){
   $scope.holidayInfo = function () {
       console.log("i am trigeered ....")
   };
})
```

Do update question with more info if you still found an issue.

Comment: not worked. I tired <li><a ng-href=""  ng-click="holidayInfo()">Holiday</a></li>

Comment: @fresher have you look at updated answer..question is little unclear that's why I can't give proper answer..could you update your question, if updated answer doesn't work..

Comment: I updated the question above. Still not able to resolve it.